# How to use newPosition(element, offset) in Google Document?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to place the cursor at the beginning of a new line after an already taken position :

```
var position = document.getCursor();
```

I tried to use `document.newPosition(element, offset)` but I don't know what to put in element and in offset, if someone could help me i would really appreciate it.

Comment: I think using the document.newPosition(element, offset) method, you can only set the new position to an element such as either a Text element or a container element like Paragraph. Check this description [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#newPosition(Element,Integer)). You cannot set the cursor to a new line position. One way to do it would be to get the cursor to end of the document body and add a page break element and set the cursor to that position. Hope that helps!